# Rubymine error log message: Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rubymine

on my rails log, I used to get  "Unpermitted parameter: :first_name"
I was able to research the answer to my problem and got it fixed. However, I would like to understand this error a bit more. So what does this error actually mean? can someone elaborate a bit more as of why this happens?

Comment: [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) might help.

Comment: I understood the part that Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been "whitelisted". But what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Try asking the googlie about "rails mass assignment vulnerability"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have rails 4 or upgraded version or you have strong_parameters gem.

> With strong_parameters plugin Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted. This means you'll have to make a conscious choice about which attributes to allow for mass updating and thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed.

For example if you have any login page and have 2 fields username and password and any other user tries to send any other parameter (email) than that email is not white listed and you will have same `Unpermitted parameter: :email`. We define which attributes a user can interact with.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you Manishh! Your explanation was simple and straight to the point